# What can be a solution when my wordpress is extremely slow?

Tags: performance

When I was writing a blog article today, I realized that my wordpress suddenly became extremely slow. Until yesterday it'd been working totally fine.

To give you some background information, I'll write down what I have searched and tried by myself.

[What I have found out]

- It is not an Internet connection problem. I could open my Facebook and other websites totally fine. Rather, they were responding pretty fast.
- I used "PageSpeed Insights" to check if my wordpress was actually slow. On a scale of 0 to 100, the assessment result was 25, which means that my wordpress was actually very slow.

[What I have tried]

- I deleted the cache. First I tried deleting my browser's cache (Google Chrome). It had no effect, so I also tried deleting my wordpress's cache.

When I deleted my wordpress's cache for the first time it seemed to be working. It began to load pages properly again and I could post and edit my articles. But several minutes later it just got back to the "frozen" state. Now it's extremely slow again.

I googled even more, and one of the pages that I found says that some other things that can make your wordpress slow are

- Theme of the wordpress
- Plugin
- Source code
- Photos

etc.

I don't think the theme is the cause of this problem, because ever since I set the theme for my wordpress for the first time (November 2017) I've never changed a thing about it.

As for the source code, basically I have done very little. The last time I edited a little bit is when I got authorized for Google Adsense in the middle of January 2019.

I don't think photos are problem either. I have posted 85 articles. Considering there are many bloggers who have already posted over 500 articles with images, I can hardly believe photos that I have uploaded are so much burden on my wordpress.

I haven't installed so many plugins either. There are 9 of them that are currently active.

- AddQuicktag
- Akismet Anti-Spam
- BackWPup
- Contact Form 7
- Easy FancyBox
- Jetpack by WordPress.com
- Ptengine - Real time web analytics and Heatmap
- Shortcodes Ultimate
- TinyMCE Annotate
- WP Fastest Cache

Any idea what can be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** (if this is right then the solution was very quick) if the website is slow and then after deleting the 'WP Fastest Cache' cache it was temporarily fast again and then slowed down, it really sounds to me like that plugin is the culprit.  Try disabling that plugin first and see if that fixes the problem.

**Second** (only if #1 fails) we may need to optimize the site, get [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-optimize/)

**Third** if both #1 and #2 fail, go to https://www.webpagetest.org/ to get a more detailed view of what is slowing down your site and share a link to the results.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. There are 9 plugins that are active at this moment. Which one should I disable? Do you mean that I need to disable all of them at once, or try one by one to see which particular plugin is the culprit?

Comment: Oh wait, I've just realized that I misunderstood earlier. You meant that "WP Fastest Cache" is the one I should try disabling.

Comment: Yes, first try disabling that plugin to see if that fixes the issue. If not, try disabling each of the other plugins until you find the one causing the problems.

Comment: I tried disabling each of the plugins one by one, and the score of the assessment went up to 65 from 25 on this website https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsonotasan.com%2F

Comment: but it doesn't improve the score further. Isn't there anything else to do?

Comment: yes there is, but now you know that the plugins or a plugin is responsible for slowing the site down 40%.  Anyway, there are several other things to do, you can optimize the database, use a cdn, minify images, etc there are a lot of things, use that website to help you pinpoint the exact problem. (btw please choose my answer as a solution because I cannot comment on other people's posts unless I am at 50 reputation)

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if the plugins are so much responsible. I visited the developers.google/.com/speed/pagespeed page once again just a few minutes ago, and the score was down to 45. And another question is, suppose that one particular plugin was slowing down the site but that was the very plugin I needed the most, how could I fix the problem without disabling the plugin?

Comment: I did not give you a link to the google page test.

and yes based on the evidence you yourself gave the number changed pretty drastically after disabling the plugins so those plugins are definitely partially to blame.  If you need a certain plugin but it is slowing down your site get a different plugin that is programmed better to do the same thing and replace the old plugin.

Comment: I guess you fixed it?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't fixed it yet. The score is still 46. I tried the link you gave me earlier, but I don't know how to read this result. https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190613_8C_b30b5980eeafa6363ab9ac33eeca3ebf/

Comment: hmm firstly and most importantly, your site isn't THAT slow.  the load time is a little over 5 seconds and I have seen a lot worse.  Your two main problems are your ttfb (time to first byte) and the fact that you do not cache static content.  The problem with you Ttfb is from your host (shared hosting I'm guessing) and the cache static content problem can be solved with a plugin that does that for you.

Comment: you also have two items:
http://sonotasan.com/2019/04/19/page-80%ef%bc%9a%e3%81%93%e3%81%86%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e5%83%95%e3%81%af%e3%83%95%e3%82%a3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%a9%e3%83%b3%e3%83%89%e3%81%a7%e4%bb%95%e4%ba%8b%e3%82%92%e3%82%b2%e3%83%83%e3%83%88%e3%81%97/embed/
and
http://sonotasan.com/2019/04/16/page-78%ef%bc%9a%e7%8f%be%e5%bd%b9%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e3%83%a9%e3%83%9e%e3%83%bc%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%82%82%e3%82%89%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%80%81it%e6%a5%ad%e7%95%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ae%e5%b0%b1/embed/
which are requests that visitors to your site have to make which take almost two seconds each

Comment: I guess the reason my blog is not that slow now is that I updated old plugins. When I posted this question there were many plugins that I hadn't updated for a while, and once I updated them the score improved from 25 to 65.

Comment: So if my host turns out to be a shared host and I want to fix it, will I have to change it to a managed host? What do you mean by "cache static content problem can be solved with a plugin"? Do you mean that I need to install a plugin that clears cache, like WP Fastest Cache and clear the cache on a regular basis?

Comment: The two embedded items are the links for my older blog posts, and besides the two links you mentioned there are many more embedded links. Are they (the two items you mentioned) the only embedded items that are slowing down my blog, or do embedded links in general slow down the blog?

Comment: 1. Please mark my answer as the solution so I get the points.  Marking a solution will not close the thread so we can still comment here afterwards.  I know I should get triple points for answering questions for so long, but I will settle for the regular number of points.
2.  Probably, but I cannot comment about that, you would have to ask your host.
3. WP Fastest Cache does not clear the cache but that is the plugin you need.  Read the plugin description if you are interested in seeing what it does.
4. No links do not slow sites down, it seems that just those two are doing something weird,

Comment: Thanks for the support so far. My blog at least got out of the "extremely slow" state, which I can live with. I'll work on it a little bit more when I have time.

Comment: oh thats great news!  I'm glad your site is not as slow as before.  When you have time look into optimizing your database!